# Button text font size based on the size of the button

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to resize the text inside my button based on the size of my button. How can I do it?

```xml
<Button StyleClass="btnFAF" Text="Field Activity" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="btnFAF" Clicked="btnFAF_Clicked" BorderRadius="6">
    <Button.FontFamily>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="OpenSans-Regular.ttf#OpenSans-Regular"/>
        </OnPlatform>
    </Button.FontFamily>
 </Button>
```

Comment: Are you using the lastest xamarin forms 3.3?

Comment: @hashimks yes  i am using the latest version of xamarin form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **Custom Renderer**

**In Forms Shared Project:**

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Content = new StackLayout
    {
        Children = { new MyButton { Text="XXXX", WidthRequest=50, HeightRequest=20 } },
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    };
}
```

And you can define a subclass of Button:

```cs
namespace App11 {
    public class MyButton : Button {
            public MyButton() 
            { }
        }
    }
```

**In iOS:**

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyButton), typeof(MyiOSButton))]
namespace xxx.iOS 
{
    class MyiOSButton : ButtonRenderer
    {
        public MyiOSButton()
        { }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e) 
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if(Control != null)
            {
                Control.TitleLabel.SizeToFit();
                Control.TitleLabel.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**In Android:**

```cs
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(MyButton), typeof(MyAndroidClass))]
namespace _1111111.Droid
{
    public class AutoFitButton : Android.Widget.Button
    {
        public AutoFitButton(Context context) : base(context) 
        { }

        protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas) 
        {
            base.OnDraw(canvas);
            SetAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(AutoSizeTextType.Uniform);
        }
    }
 
    public class MyAndroidClass : ButtonRenderer
    {
        IElementController ElementController => Element as IElementController;
        public MyAndroidClass(Context context) : base(context)
        { }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if(Control != null) 
            {
                SetNativeControl(new AutoFitButton(Context));
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            base.OnDraw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice:the method `SetAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(AutoSizeTextType.Uniform)` is only available after Android O (API 26).

Comment: notes: add padding to make the text somewhat smaller than the button and center it. different texts will have different sizes - so if you have multiple buttons, it won't look that nice

Comment: iOS works great, but the Android one will disregard my styling

Answer (score 0):

Let me propose you a workaround if you are not targeting low Android versions (around < 21) where this doesn't look anti-aliased. 
You can create a "standart" button with a defined FontSize, then just apply Scale to it, to make it bigger: the button and the text will be scaled accordingly.

```
<ui:MyButton Scale="1.5" x:Name="MyBigButton"/>
```